# How to create a coupon on specific product in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, reduction, discounts

Let's say I have 10% off coupon code.
This coupon is applicable only to Product B

A customer have in its cart :

- Product P1
- **Product B**
- Product P2

I don't want my 10% off coupon apply to other product but only to Product B.

Do you know how I can do that within Magento?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here is the process to create **Coupon Code** for any particular product:-

> - Login to Admin
> - Go to **Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules**
> - Click Add New Rule
> - Fill Rule Information

**Set Conditions**

> - On left sidebar, click **Conditions** tab
> - Click + button icon
> - Select **Product attribute combination**
> - Click + button icon
> - Select **SKU**
> - Now, you will see **SKU is ...**
> - Put your product SKU over there

***Please note*** that the SKU option may not show up by default. (*Go to: catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes. Then search for the ‘SKU’ attribute and set the drop down ‘Use for Promo Rule Conditions’ to YES and reindex if needed.)*

**Set Actions**

> - You can set how much discount you want to give from here
> - **Save Rule**

Comment: Please note that the SKU option may not show up by default. If that happens you have to activate the SKU attribute for coupons: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/227594/#t325609

Answer (score 10):

They are not exact answer for the question.
Most of all the right but you have to setup one more thing as below if you want to discount only specific items or specific items in category.

1. Do it as above
   under Shopping Cart Price Rule
2. Go to Conditions > Remove all conditions
3. **Go to Actions** and setup under 
   "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)"

   - If you want to discount specific items, select SKU and input the SKU #
   - If you want to discount Category items, select category

It will be discounted only setup items even if other items are in the cart.

Comment: This is the exact answer. Thank you @Michael.

Answer (score 9):

Also as extra information, if you not found SKU in promotion tab you can do following.

**Go to: catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes**

Search for the ‘SKU’ attribute and set the drop down ‘Use for Promo Rule Conditions’ on YES.

That will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your shopping cart rules in Admin Panel of Magento. When you create new rule, under conditions tab you have great options to set.

For example you can that this rule will apply only to products of a one category, or product which has defined attribute.

You should check those option, because Magento has many possibilities here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to Admin
2. Go to Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules
3. Click Add New Rule
4. Fill Rule Information

Under Actions :

1. In Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)
2. Click on + button, under that select SKU
3. Now, you can see SKU is ...
4. Put your product SKU over there

The SKU option wont be there in default, to add that

> Catalog -> attributes -> manage attributes
>   Find SKU

Set "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" to Yes