# Magento Simple Configurable Products and Discounts

Tags: magento

I have Simple configurable products installed on magento.  How can I apply a discount to a configurable product which makes sure that all the simple products associated to the configurable also get the discount applied to them?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Magento's Catalog Price Rules (Admin > Promotions > Catalog Price Rules).

There's some good information on how these work here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-catalog-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, however this still doesn't solve my problem.  I want to set a discount against a configurable product and have that discount applied to all products within that configurable product.  This doesn't currently happen if I apply a discount via sku to a configurable product, the simple products associated do not inherit the discount.

Comment: What type of rule are you trying to apply Catalog or Shopping Cart ?

Comment: That's my point Lucas, Add all of the sku's to the catalog rule. It's not "inheritance" so to speak, but Magento isn't built to inherit rules or discounts like you described.

Answer (score -1):

I was also looking for the answer to this, but unfortunately didn't found it yet.

Below helped though. In addition to below, what i did is instead of selecting config product SKU, i selected all the simple product SKU which are part of that config product.
[How to create a coupon on specific product in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338305/how-to-create-a-coupon-on-specific-product-in-magento)